# Role of Intensity Modulator's Extinction Ratio on transmitter side in COW/DPS QKD using Weak Coherent Pulses

Tags: quantum-state, key-distribution, quantum-optics, qkd

What is the role of having a high extinction ratio (30-40 dB) for the intensity modulator on the transmitter side in COW/DPS QKD using Weak Coherent Pulses, when ultimately the pulses have to be attenuated using an attenuator to achieve the single photon pulses and required mean photon number?

Is there any impact of extinction ratio on timing between pulses in case of COW or phase modulation in case of DPS QKD? or is there any other impact that I am missing?

Also do pulse duration and repetition rate in COW/DPS protocols have any relation with extinction ratio required for the Intensity Modulator?

Thanks